# node Issue in Creating demo project using react_on_rails gem

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, ruby-on-rails-5.1, react-on-rails

I am trying to follow this [tutorial](https://shakacode.gitbooks.io/react-on-rails/content/docs/tutorial.html) to create a dummy project using gem react_on_rails

I guess I have followed every step of the tutorial but on the last step where we have to run the project a node js related  error is popping up.
I even updated my node version on the system, still facing the same issue

Error

```
foreman start -f Procfile.dev
22:30:58 web.1    | started with pid 5370
22:30:58 client.1 | started with pid 5371
22:30:59 client.1 | (in /home/projects/test-react-on-rails)
22:31:00 web.1    | => Booting Puma
22:31:00 web.1    | => Rails 5.1.2 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
22:31:00 web.1    | => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
22:31:00 web.1    | Puma starting in single mode...
22:31:00 web.1    | * Version 3.9.1 (ruby 2.4.0-p0), codename: Private Caller
22:31:00 web.1    | * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
22:31:00 web.1    | * Environment: development
22:31:00 web.1    | * Listening on tcp://localhost:3000
22:31:00 web.1    | Use Ctrl-C to stop
22:31:01 client.1 | yarn run v0.27.5
22:31:01 client.1 | $ NODE_ENV=development webpack -w --config webpack.config.js
22:31:01 client.1 | /home/projects/test-react-on-rails/client/webpack.config.js:6
22:31:01 client.1 | const {resolve } = require('path');
22:31:01 client.1 |       ^
22:31:01 client.1 | 
22:31:01 client.1 | SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
22:31:01 client.1 |     at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
22:31:01 client.1 |     at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
22:31:01 client.1 |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
22:31:01 client.1 |     at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
22:31:01 client.1 |     at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
22:31:01 client.1 |     at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
22:31:01 client.1 |     at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
22:31:01 client.1 |     at requireConfig (/home/shubhangi/projects/test-react-on-rails/client/node_modules/webpack/bin/convert-argv.js:96:18)
22:31:01 client.1 |     at /home/projects/test-react-on-rails/client/node_modules/webpack/bin/convert-argv.js:109:17
22:31:01 client.1 |     at Array.forEach (native)
22:31:01 client.1 | error Command failed with exit code 1.
22:31:01 client.1 | info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
22:31:02 client.1 | exited with code 1
22:31:02 system   | sending SIGTERM to all processes
22:31:02 web.1    | - Gracefully stopping, waiting for requests to finish
22:31:02 web.1    | === puma shutdown: 2017-07-27 22:31:02 +0530 ===
22:31:02 web.1    | - Goodbye!
22:31:02 web.1    | Exiting
22:31:02 web.1    | exited with code 0
```

Comment: What is your Node version? You can run `node --version` to find out.

Comment: my current version is v4.8.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use [object destructuring](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_destructuring.html), which was first [supported in Node version 6](http://node.green/#ES2015-syntax-destructuring--declarations), and is not available in Node 4.

You should upgrade your Node version, especially since version 4 is no longer actively maintained, which means that only *critical* fixes are applied, until it reaches the end of life (for details see [LTS schedule](https://github.com/nodejs/LTS#lts-schedule1)).

If you still have to use Node 4, you cannot use object destructuring and have to change the line to:

```
const resolve = require('path').resolve;
```

Another possibility would be to transpile the unsupported features with Babel, but that seems a little heavy handed for a config.